# Tkinter - How can I change the background color for the TTK Lable widgets set in "readonly" mode?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

if I set a TTK Label in "readonly" mode, its background color changes from white to grey. how can I prevent this color change?

below an example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent=Tk()
        self.parent.geometry("260x180")
        self.parent.title("TEST")
        self.parent.configure(background="#f0f0f0")
        
        self.SV=StringVar()
        self.SV.set("Ciao")
        self.MyLabel=ttk.Entry(self.parent, state="readonly", textvariable=self.SV)
        self.MyLabel.place(x=20, y=20)
        
        self.parent.mainloop()

obj=Test()
```

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://tkdocs.com/shipman/ttk-map.html.

Comment: ciao Bryan, in according with the documentation, I tried to create a custom style for the TTK Label objects, using the `style.map("TEntry", background=[("readonly", "white")])` instruction, but nothing change (`style` comes from `style=ttk.Style()`) but with the `foreground` option it works, why? where am I wrong? how can I change the background of the TTK Label objects in "readonly" mode?

Comment: no ideas about the issue?

Comment: It could be that the theme you're using on your platform doesn't allow you to change the background color. Some platforms are that way. The code in your comment works for me on OSX.

Comment: I'm on windows 10 and it doesn't work. uff.. I worked with Tkinter a long time and as time goes by, I'm more convinced that Tkinter is not a good choise for professional GUI. it's too complicate, even if the issue is not so important like in this case.

Comment: It would help if your question had a complete [mcve]. The one you posted doesn't show you attempting to change the style.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter - Can I change the background color for a TTK Label set in ReadOnly mode? I tried but it didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65895321/tkinter-can-i-change-the-background-color-for-a-ttk-label-set-in-readonly-mode)